# Laravel Api -> restrict Telescope on production

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-6, telescope

I developed a laravel API and installed laravel telescope. I want to restrict telescope on prod server, but I don't know how to do it. Solution I found is with Gate, but not working. So my idea is how to restrict route only to specific people (1 or 2). Now all users have access to /telescope.

```
 Gate::define('viewTelescope', function ($user) {
        return in_array($user->email, [
            //emails
        ]);
    });
```

Comment: What file did you place the above `Gate` in? When you say it is not working, what do you mean? Is it not letting any users access, or is it letting all users access, or something else entirely?

Comment: oo yea sorry letting all users access. The Gate is inside of TelescopeServiceProvider.php

Comment: How does your gate not work, show how you use it and define it?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you must have set the environment to local in the .env file of the server.

so just change APP_ENV=production in your server .env file

hope this helps for anyone looking for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can also limit access to telescope by user id:

in app\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider.php

```
protected function gate()
{
    Gate::define('viewTelescope', function ($user) {
     return in_array($user->id, [2,10,57,128,]);
        });
}
```

then add this code to config/telescope.php

```
    'watchers' => [
.
.
.
        Watchers\GateWatcher::class => [
            'enabled' => env('TELESCOPE_GATE_WATCHER', true),
            'ignore_abilities' => [],
            'ignore_packages' => true,
        ],
.
.
.
    ],
```

this works just in production mode.

at the end should be noted(based on laravel docs):

> You should ensure you change your APP_ENV environment variable to
> production in your production environment. Otherwise, your Telescope
> installation will be publicly available.